# Cordova app crashes with Dialog onPause

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I have built a Cordova app with the **org.apache.cordova.dialogs** plugin installed.
After starting (onDeviceReady) I show the dialog using `navigator.notification.alert\prompt`.

Then if i press HOME button to return to the home screen I get the following error:

```
The app crashes: Unable to add window — token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running?
```

How can I overcome this? I have already done a research on this topic but found no ideas on how to implement it using Cordova.

Comment: android version? cordova version? plugin version? I've just tested and I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Android 5.1.1
Cordova 5.1.1 (cordova -v in the project dir)
Cordova 4.0.2 (platforms/cordova/version file)
Plugin org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.3.0 "Notification"

Comment: latest dialogs plugin is 1.1.1, try it. If you still have the problen, file an issue on http://issues.cordova.io/